# How to increase translating content size in Google translator API

Tags: php, google-translate

I am using google translator API.

```
function curl($url,$params = array(),$is_coockie_set = false)
{

if(!$is_coockie_set){
/* STEP 1. let’s create a cookie file */
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

/* STEP 2. visit the homepage to set the cookie properly */
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
}

$str = ''; $str_arr= array();
foreach($params as $key => $value)
{
$str_arr[] = urlencode($key)."=".urlencode($value);
}
if(!empty($str_arr))
$str = '?'.implode('&',$str_arr);

/* STEP 3. visit cookiepage.php */

$Url = $url.$str;

$ch = curl_init ($Url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec ($ch);
return $output;
}
```

In this Google API, 500 characters only translated.

```
function Translate($word,$conversion)
{
$word = urlencode($word);
$url = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&text='.$word.'&hl=en&sl=en&tl=fr&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&multires=1&otf=1&ssel=3&tsel=3&sc=1';
}
```

This is function used to translate content.I want to translate more than 500 characters.
Please advice me.

Comment: Are you using the paid of the free version of the API, because you have to pay for it. https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/faq - If you pay for it; `What is the maximum number of characters per request?
The maximum size of each text to be translated is 5000 characters, not including any HTML tags.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seen in: [How to increase translating content size in Google translator API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630809/how-to-increase-translating-content-size-in-google-translator-api)

> > Is there any free quota?
> >     No, the Google Translate API is only available as a paid service. Please see Pricing and Support for more details. However we do offer the Google Website Translator gadget, which will translate your website without charge.